# MVC Multiple ViewPage items in aspx required

Tags: model-view-controller, viewpage

I need to pass in 2 objects to a page to access Model.NewsItems and Model.Links
(the first is a class of news item objects with heading, content etc and the Links are a set of strings for hyperlink depending on whether the system is up or down.

This is the page declaration

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"  
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Tolling.Models.NewsItems>" %>
```

If I refer to `Model.Items` - I am fine.
However, if I refer to `Model.HyperLink1`, I am not.

How can you pass in multiple objects into the page?
I have tried importing both namespaces without success - i.e.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Tolling.Models.News" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Tolling.Models.HyperLinks" %>
```

Comment: sorry that declaration was Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Tolling.Models.NewsItems>

Comment: Are you aware that you can edit your posts?

Answer (score 1):

Create a ViewModel class that contains both of your model collections and then pass that too the view:

Sample Controller:

```
var myNewModel = new MyNewModel()
{ 
    NewsItems = new List<NewItem>(), 
    HyperLinks = new List<HyperLink>() 
}

return View(myNewModel);
```

View page declaration:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"  
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyNewModel>" %>
```

Then you can access them in your view with your new ViewModels properties:

```
<%= Model.NewsItems %>
<%= Model.Hyperlinks %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass extra data into the View by using ViewData, TempData, Session or Cache. I'd suggest you use [ViewData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata(VS.100).aspx). As described by MSDN:

> Gets or sets a dictionary that
>   contains data to pass between the
>   controller and the view.